# Dynamically call php object method based on test?

Tags: php, object, dynamic, methods

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to call a php object's method based on the success of a test? For example below...

Normal usage:

```
$obj = new obj;
$obj->call()
    ->successive()
    ->methods();
```

Running test to see if method should be called:

```
$obj = new obj;
$obj->call()
    ( if ($a) ? ->successive() : '')
    ->methods();
```

Is there any way to make the second example above work? Or another way to achieve the same result? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps?

```
$obj = new obj;
$temp = $obj->call();
if ($a) {
   $temp = $temp->successive();
}
$temp->methods();
```

Comment: or you could do `->successive(a)->` and then perdform check inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps pass the methods name to `.successive()` and deal it as a callback.

```
class obj {
  private $is_success;

  public function call() {
     $this->is_success = return_a_boolean();
     return $this;
  }

  public function successive($callback) {
     if ($this->is_success && method_exists($this, $callback)) {
        $this->$callback();
     }
     return $this;
  }

  public function methods() {
      //....
  }
}

$obj = new obj;
$obj->call()
    ->successive('methods');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a fallback method to execute when the test fails you could structure it like this, I think:

```
$obj = new obj;
$obj->call()
    ->{ $a ? "successive" : "fallback_method"}()
    ->methods();
```

Would that help?  You'd probably want the fallback method to look like:

```
function fallback_method() {
    return $this;
}
```